# BeautifulSoup searching for specific children

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, element, children

I would like to search through child elements for specific attributes using BeautifulSoup, from what I can see using the below method each child is a string (child['value'] gives me "string indices must be integers"), which does not allow selection based on attributes or returning of those attributes, which incidently is what I need to do.

```
def get_value(container):
    html_file = open(html_path)
    html = html_file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    values = {}
    container = soup.find(attrs={"name" : container})
    if (container.contents != []):
        for child in container.children:
            value = unicode(child['value']) # i would like to be able to search throught these children based on their attributes, and return one or more of their values
return value
```

Could probably get around this with a further `child_soup Beautifulsoup(child)` and then a find command but this seems really horrible, anyone got a better solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`container.children` is a generator that provides `Tag` objects, so you can operate on them normally.

You also might want to try `element.find_all(..., recursive=False)` in order to look for an element's direct children with some traits.

Comment: child['value'] gives me "string indices must be integers" so i assumed it was a string, any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, good point. The children are `Tag`s and [`NavigableString`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring)s.

Comment: but actually that element.find_all() worked beautifully, thanks!

Comment: does this not work for XML? because I've just used this on an xml file in so many different ways, but at the point where I should get the attribute value I just get an index error when I use [0] on a findAll return object, or I simply get a blank result